# Is it posible to push an array into a queue or stack in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, queue

I know that I can place integers or characters into a queue or stack but how about pushing a whole array?

```
var stack = [];
stack.push(2);       // stack is now [2]
stack.push(5);       // stack is now [2, 5]
var i = stack.pop(); // stack is now [2]
alert(i);            // displays 5

var queue = [];
queue.push(2);         // queue is now [2]
queue.push(5);         // queue is now [2, 5]
var i = queue.shift(); // queue is now [5]
alert(i);              // displays 2
```

Let's say I have data that is being sent from the client to the server, which needs to store them to release them at a later time. I'm sending three fields, *username*, *message*, and *avatar*.

Example:

```
['simon','this is a message','avatar.png']
```

and

```
['Muray','this is another message','avatar2.png']
```

These two arrays should be sent to the server and the entire array popped when needed.

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: Arrays can contain anything you want, including other arrays.

Comment: Are you asking if you can push an array into an array? If yes, then yes you can push an array into an array.

Comment: You've already written the idea of stack (:   read this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1796-javascript-array-methods-unshift-shift-push-and-pop.htm

Comment: so would it be queue.push(['simon','this is a message','avatar.png']);?

Comment: Why don't you just try it in your browser console and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, queue.push(['simon','this is a message','avatar.png']); works, then if you do queue.push([5,2]) then your queue contains : [ ['simon','this is a message','avatar.png'], [5,2] ]

Comment: @learningbyexample If you’re working in a browser, press F12 right now, then in the console, enter `queue = [];` and then your suggestion. You can find out yourself, whether this works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can push/pop entire arrays into/out of arrays in JavaScript.

For example:

```
var a = [];
a.push([1, 2, 3, 4]);
a.pop(); // yields [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In your example, you would do:

```
var a = [];
a.push(['simon','this is a message','avatar.png']);
a.push(['Muray','this is another message','avatar2.png']);
```

You can also define a nested array in one step:

```
var a = [
  ['simon','this is a message','avatar.png'],
  ['Muray','this is another message','avatar2.png']];
```

If you're sending it to a server, you may want to `JSON` encode it using `JSON.stringify` like so:

```
JSON.stringify(a);
```

Which would yield a string containing

> [["simon","this is a message","avatar.png"],["Muray","this is another message","avatar2.png"]]